# How do I hide Visual Studio Add-in disabled commands

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, visual-studio-addins

I created a Visual Studio Add-in that adds additional commands (four of them) to the top of *Code Window* context menu. I'm using permanent UI approach. Depending on the cursor position within code only one of the commands would be visible and thus selectable. Other three would be hidden.

I set *supported* and *enabled* status within `QueryStatus` method that does the trick for the correct command and *unsupported* and *invisible* for the rest.

**The problem**
The first time add-in is installed all works well. I can only see a **single** command in the context menu. The rest are always hidden.
The second time I load VS IDE I detect the same commands and controls (so I don't recreate something that's already there), but now all of the commands (or better 
`CommandBarControl/CommandBarButton` controls) are visible. Instead of hiding 3 and showing only one I can see **all four of them**. The correct one is enabled and the rest of the pack is disabled/grayed out.

**The question**
How do I hide existing commands (or `CommandBarButton` controls) on the next IDE load? I tried setting button's `Visible` property to `false` but then even the correct control isn't displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I used at the end was:

1. Delete controls at IDE startup (or Add-in after startup if not enabled at IDE startup by default). Deleting commands also removes any controls
2. Recreate commands and controls and their visibility will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having a single command, and changing the text of command depending on the cursor position? I'm not sure if this is possible, just a suggestion.